# Submit forms in django without refreshing the page

Tags: django, ajax, chat

Okay, first of all, I know that there are a lot of videos and tutorials out there to help with the question I have raised. However, my case is a little different than the usual. So, basically, I am trying to build out a chat app on Django. For this I am planning to save the messages that the user wants to send in the database and then render them on screen. **Now, in order to send this data to the server, I wish to use Ajax as it would prevent page reload and thus make for a much smoother UX**. However, that raises an issue. **The issue is that how do I keep track of the fact that which room/ chat is the message coming from and which user sent it?** The obvious solution that comes to mind is the create a hidden field inside if my form and then pass in the room details of it through that hidden field. **But won't that be highly insecure as the data could be subject to change, allowing users to send messages from a chat they have access to, to a chat they don't have access to?** The username part can still be managed using request.user. The trouble is arising only with the tracking room details part.
Any help/ideas are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: "_But won't that be highly insecure as the data could be subject to change, allowing users to send messages from a chat they have access to, to a chat they don't have access to_" you obviously have to add that validation on the server side... It's not like the AJAX is what's making that vulnerable it would have been possible even if you submitted the form normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all take a look at Django Unicorn:
https://www.django-unicorn.com/

This might be the perfect fit for this kind of application.

> But won't that be highly insecure as the data could be subject to change, allowing users to send messages from a chat they have access to, to a chat they don't have access to?

As Abdul Aziz Barkat already pointet out is true for all kind of form submission. You have to check in your code if the user is allowed to post to/from a room and to a person. This can be done in the forms `clean()` method where you can raise errors like PermissionDenied.

### Edit

response to your first comment:

You need to keep track permissions of the chat. e.g. which users are allowed to write in this chat and those that are allowed to read the chat

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    # your generic chat class
    # ...
    write = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="users_write_access")
    read = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="user_read_access")
```

As soon as a user becomes a member of a chat add them to the write and read field.

If a user tries to send a message to a chat check if he's a member of the write list. e.g.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import PermissionDenied

def send_message_to_chat(request, chat_id):
    chat = get_object_or_404(Chat, pk=chat_id)
    if request.user not in chat.write.all():
        raise PermissionDenied("You are not allowed to write in this chat...")
    # continue with your code to send messages
```

to something similar for read access. I hope this helps

Comment: I understand this but the current vulnerability that I see in my application is that a user can type a message in one chat, hit send and then intercept the request and change the chat_id parameter that I use to keep track of the id of the chat to some other chat that they are a member of. This'll allow them to send messages across chats. This alone is not too much of a concern but I am worried that this may be leveraged for a better attack....any suggestions?

Comment: I've edited the answer with an answer to your question